# Visual Studio - Markup syntax highlighting inside script[type:txt/html]

Tags: visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting, markup

Does anyone know how or if its possible for Visual Studio 2008 to highlight the html syntax inside a script block of type "text/html" just like any other markup on an aspx/html page.  I'm using the script block to house my templates for client-side templating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind, assuming the page itself is an ASP.NET page (and not a plain HTML page) :

1. create a custom control which emits the `script` tag and end-tag.  By using a custom control, you'll fool the IDE into not knowing about the `script` tag, and so you'll get the same syntax coloring as the enclosing page's HTML
2. extract the script block's contents into a user control, and place an instance of that user control inside the script block. Since VS doesn't know that the user control's content will be inside a script block, you'll get syntax coloring.

I like the first option better, as it doesn't force you to split your page into multiple files.

If it's a plain HTML page, there's not many easy ways to do this. If "not easy" is OK, then you can alwasy create an [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) which replaces a placeholder tag in the source code (e.g. `<myscript>`) with, upon output to the user, a real text/html script tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is now a part of Visual Studio if you add Web Tools 2012.2:

http://vswebessentials.com/features/html

Be sure to use type="text/html" on the script tag.