# KnockoutJs and Templates - No code highlighting / completion in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, knockout.js

I have been playing with the tutorials on the knockout site and have enjoyed working with it.

So i decided to make a simple site with it. I was saddened to notice that i lose a lot of the support from the IDE when working with the javascript templates (highlighting, code completion)

Example template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="taskTemplate">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, enable: !isDone()" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: remove">Delete</a>
    </li>
</script>
```

Is this something you have to just swallow or is it avoidable / fixable?
Templates seem to be one of the most used ways of building up the page and so i would prefer to have the support from the IDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get around this I create two html helpers for the begining of my script tag and the end of my script tag. Something like:

```
<% Html.BeginTemplate(new { id = "features-template" }); %>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, enable: !isDone()" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: remove">Delete</a>
    </li>
<% Html.EndTemplate(); %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Keith proposed very good and intelligent solution. However I would like to let you know KO 1.3 has native templating engine. It is avaliable trough new bindings:

- if
- ifnot
- with
- foreach!

you can read more in Steve Sanderson's announce: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/ (1. Control flow bindings)

So your example will have this look:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
    <input data-bind="value: title, enable: !isDone()" />
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: remove">Delete</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This new templating engine is very handy.  However, there are some situations where the jquery template works better.  It's classic case of no one tool can cover all situations.

Comment: Ofc jquery templates are still very useful for reusable templates. However new template engine gives us simple way as well. Like <div ko-template="tmpl">Hi there</div> <div data-bind="template: 'tmpl'"></div>. Some additional coding needed but solution is very programmer-friendly :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is the `<script type="text/html"...>` tag that is stopping Visual Studio highlight this section of your markup as html. Therefore, this question/answer seems to be the closest you are going to get to an answer.

[Visual Studio - Markup syntax highlighting inside script[type:txt/html]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678801/visual-studio-markup-syntax-highlighting-inside-scripttypetxt-html)

Answer (score 0):

I used the accepted answer here, and since it helped me, if anyone wants actual code, here you go:

```
public string StartTemplate(string id)
{
    return ("<script type=\"text/html\" id=\"" + id + "\">\r\n");
}

public string EndTemplate()
{
    return ("</script>\r\n");
}
```

HTML:

```
<%= StartTemplate("WidgetTemplate")%>
 ...actual template HTML goes here...
<%= EndTemplate() %>
```